# Object is enumerable but not indexable?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, kaggle

## Problem summary and question

I'm trying to look at some of the data inside an object that can be enumerated over but not indexed. I'm still newish to python, but I don't understand how this is possible.

If you can enumerate it, why can't you access the index through the same way enumerate does? And if not, is there a way to access the items individually?

## The actual example

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

train_validation_split = tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit([6, 4])

(train_data, validation_data), test_data = tfds.load(
    name="imdb_reviews", 
    split=(train_validation_split, tfds.Split.TEST),
    as_supervised=True)
```

Take a select subset of the dataset

```
foo = train_data.take(5)
```

I **can** iterate over `foo` with enumerate:

```
[In] for i, x in enumerate(foo):
    print(i)
```

which generates the expected output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

But then, when I try to index into it `foo[0]` I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-2acbea6d9862> in <module>
----> 1 foo[0]

TypeError: 'TakeDataset' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: Because enumerate doesn't access an index. There is no concept of "enumerable" in python, it is merely iterable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python only allows these things if the class has methods for them:

- [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) is required for the `[]` syntax.
- [`__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) and [`__next__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__)<sup>1</sup> are required to iterate.

Any class can define one without defining the other. `__getattr__` is usually not defined if it would be inefficient.

---

<sup>1</sup> `__next__` is required on the class returned by `__iter__`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a result of `foo` being iterable, but not having a `__getitem__` function. You can use [`itertools.isslice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to get the nth element of an iterable like so

```py
import itertools

def nth(iterable, n, default=None):
    "Returns the nth item or a default value"
    return next(itertools.islice(iterable, n, None), default)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, instances of custom classes can implement enumeration through special (or "dunder") `__iter__` method. Perhaps this class implements `__iter__` but not `__getitem__`.

Dunder overview: https://dbader.org/blog/python-dunder-methods
Specs for an `__iter__` method: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter

Comment: Not "enumeration" rather "iteration"